# JavaFX Label MenuItems in a ContextMenu

Tags: java, javafx

I have a need for a ContextMenu that contains Labels and normal MenuItems (buttons).

These "title"-labels should not be keyboard navigable / enabled at all. They should really work like separator items, just provide visuals.

What's a good way to achieve this? I tried to simply add MenuItems and disable them, but keyboard navigation does not work correctly with this approach.

Comment: `SeparatorMenuItem`s simply extend `CustomMenuItem`. If you want the same functionality, consider defining your own class that also extends `CustomMenuItem`.

Comment: Well, I got it working by using simply SeparatorMenuItem, and calling its setContent(Node). It seems that the keyboard skipping behaviour is hard-coded for SeparatorMenuItems.